# How to have query field with no return type // Pothos Graphql

Tags: graphql

How can I have a Pothos graphql query field with no return type? Like, I want the graphql function to not return anything.

I tried:

```
builder.queryType({
  fields: (t) => ({
    // I just put field here
    exchange: t.field({
      args: {
        code: t.arg.string(),
      },
      resolve: (parent, { code }) => {
        console.log(code);
        // No return here
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `query` must return something, maybe what you are willing to do is a `mutation`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Looking at the Pothos docs, it seems like mutations must still return something. Maybe I'm implementing it wrong? How would you write the `mutationField`?

Answer (score 0):

Every field in GraphQL must return something.  If you don't want to return any meaningful data, you can return a boolean instead (maybe indicating if the operation succeeded).  If you are not returning data, I assume this is trying to run some mutation, in which case, using a mutation would be more appropriate:

```js
  builder.mutationType({
    fields: (t) => ({
      // I just put field here
      exchange: t.field({
        type: 'Boolean',
        args: {
          code: t.arg.string(),
        },
        resolve: (parent, { code }) => {
          console.log(code);
          return true;
        },
      }),
    }),
  });
```

You can also make any field in GraphQL nullable, which allows you to return null from your resolver.  In Pothos you can do this by setting the `nullable` option for the field to `true`.